# Parse multiple identical argument groups with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have been searching a lot through argparse posts here but can't really find anything related to the issue I'm having.
I need to parse a command line that takes multiple images and their optional characteristics as an input. 
For example I want to parse a command line like this:

`image_tool.py  -n 3 image_1 -c green -y 3 image_2 -x 2 -y 7 image_3 -c black -x 10`

The output I get with below test program is correct.

```
('green', '3', '3')
('red', '2', '7')
('black', '10', '5')
```

But the issue is when I try to get the help I'm just getting:

```
$image_tool.py -h
usage: image_tool [-h] [-n NUM_IMAGES] [-m MODE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n NUM_IMAGES, --num_images NUM_IMAGES  Number of Images
  -m MODE, --mode MODE  Tool mode
```

No mention of the image_* arguments or subparsers. Even with `image_tool.py  image_1 -h` I'm getting the same output.
Anyone knows how to get the help for the image supparsers? Ideally I would like to get the help for all parameters with `image_tool.py -h`

I'm also wondering if I'm abusing the subparser functionality here. Does anyone have a better suggestion to achieve the same functionality? Argument groups, different parser library, ...? Looks like what I need is an 'append' feature for subparsers that creates a list of Namespaces.
An easier way is probably to parse a json file with the image information, but right now I'm limited to command line.

Thanks!

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='image_tool')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--num_images', dest='num_images', type=int, action='store', default='2', help='Number of Images')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', action='store', dest='mode', help="Tool mode")

options, argv = parser.parse_known_args()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-help', dest='sp_image')

for i in range(0,options.num_images+1):
    sp= subparsers.add_parser('image_%i'%i, help='image help')
    sp.add_argument("-c", "--color", action="store", dest='color', default='red', help="Color")
    sp.add_argument("-x", "--width", action="store", dest='width', default='3', help="Width")
    sp.add_argument("-y", "--height", action="store", dest='height', default='5', help="Height")

image = []
while argv:
    print('Remaining command line ', argv)
    # Only use one image to allow duplicates
    try:
        index = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(argv[1:]) if s.startswith('image_')][0]
    except IndexError:
        #last one
        index = idx+1
    opt = parser.parse_args(argv[:index+1])
    # Cut off first image from command line
    argv = argv[index+1:]
    image.append(opt)
    if not opt.sp_image:
        break

# Test code
for img in image:
    print (img.color, img.width, img.height)
```

Comment: The [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) module is pretty handy and my goto for command line processing

Comment: The help is easily explained.  The first `parse_known_args` catches the `-h` and issues the help.  All that you define at the point are -n and -m.  You add the subparsers later, so they don't show up in the help.

Comment: How attached are you to that particular CLI?

Comment: I'd just define one independent parser that handles `c,x,y` and call it repeatedly for each `image` subgroup.  No need to use the subparsers mechanism.

Comment: A simpler CLI would define one argument, `add_argument('-i','--image',nargs=4, action='append')`  and `image_tool.py  -i image_1 green 3 3 -i image_2 red 2 7 -i image_3 black 10 5`.  It doesn't allow for defaults as your code, but doesn't require any more user typing.

Comment: Another thought - I've never seen someone define a bunch of subparsers after an initial read, and repeatedly call them like this.  It may work, but it's not common usage.  So don't expect `argparse` to provide much support or customization tools for doing this.

Comment: Thanks, for all the replies. Not too attached to this particular command line. But defaults would be very useful. There is a few more image properties than shown here and very often the default is fine, so defaults would shorten the command line by a lot.

Comment: @hpaulj your explanation makes sense. Any way to fix it?
I guess instead of subparser in a loop I could use one parser, segment the command line and then use the same parser in a loop.

Comment: At some point a json file or string might be easier to use.

Comment: It is possible to create a parser without a help argument, and add your own later.  But remember that the help with subparsers is somewhat fragmented.

Comment: @MichaelD I took a look at click. I don't think it supports what I want to do. Unless I missed something.